# Proving $|\alpha^{<\omega}| < \kappa$ without Axiom of Choice

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

Let $\kappa$ be a cardinal. Fix an ordinal $\alpha < \kappa$. Let $\alpha^{<\omega}$ denote the set of all finite sequences of ordinals less than $\alpha$. Can we show that $|\alpha^{<\omega}| < \kappa$ without invoking the Axiom of Choice?

I know it is, for instance, independent without $\mathsf{AC}$ that $\omega_1$ is a countable union of countable ordinals, but I'm unsure of variants of this statement (such as the one I posed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the well ordering of $\alpha$ we can recursively define an injection of $\alpha^n$ into $\alpha$, and this allows you to define an injection from $\alpha^{<\omega}$ into $\alpha\times\omega$, which is equipotent with $\alpha$.

More explicitly, we know that there is a function $f_2\colon\alpha^2\to\alpha$ which is a bijection: first choose a function $e\colon\alpha\to|\alpha|$, then using the Gödel pairing function we have that $|\alpha|\times|\alpha|=|\alpha|$ and applying $e^{-1}$ gives us this function.

Now, by recursion, if $f_n\colon\alpha\to\alpha^n$ is a bijection, $f_{n+1}\colon\alpha^{n+1}\to\alpha$ is defined by $$f_{n+1}(\xi_0,\dots,\xi_n)=f_2(f_n(\xi_0,\dots,\xi_{n-1}),\xi_n).$$
Now we have a sequence $\langle f_n\mid n<\omega\rangle$ of functions, where $f_1$ is the identity, and we can ignore, for a moment $f_0$, since it only adds a single point to a well-orderable infinite set. And now we can easily map $\vec\xi$ of length $n$ to the pair $\langle f_n(\vec\xi),n\rangle\in\alpha\times\omega$, and finally we have that $\alpha\times\omega$ injects into $\alpha$ since it is a subset of $\alpha\times\alpha$, and we already covered that part.

---

Alternatively, note that the set is the same in $L$, since finite sequences of ordinals are absolute, and that in $L$ the axiom of choice holds, so $\alpha$ and $\alpha^{<\omega}$ are equipotent in $L$, and therefore also in $V$.

Comment: I'm not sure what the injection into $\alpha \times \omega$ should be. Are you saying that the order-type of the well-orders of $\alpha^n$ each is $\alpha$? Because I don't see why that's the case (though I'm most likely misunderstanding something here).

Comment: Sorry, just woke up and typing this on my phone. I had meant injections into $\alpha$ are defined recursively.

Comment: I'm afraid I am still unsure what the injections of $\alpha^n$ into $\alpha$ should be. Do you mind elaborating more?

Comment: Start with $\alpha\times\alpha\to\alpha$ via the usual Gödel pairing (composed with $\alpha\to|\alpha|$, that is). Then iterate recursively.

Comment: Right, of course. But why does this not prove that the countable union of countable sets is countable without choice? Is it because if $\alpha_i$, $i < \omega$, are countable ordinals with $f_i : \alpha_i \to \omega$ injective, we may not be able to form an "overall" function $f : \omega \to (\alpha_i \to \omega)$?

Comment: What countable unions? You have defined, recursively, a sequence of injections. You hold that object *in your hand*. There is no choice involved here whatsoever.

Comment: I've elaborated on this now.